# Unable to create a Gradle task rule with an Exec task

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a task rule to create a series of tasks that checkout various svn repository locations.  Here is my rule:

```
 
tasks.addRule("Pattern: svnCheckout<Classifier> - Checks out the indicated svn repo")  { String taskName ->
  if(taskName.startsWith('svnCheckout')) {
    task(name: taskName, type: Exec) {
      String classifier = taskName - 'svnCheckout'
      String svnDir = svnRepoUrl //defined elsewhere
      switch(classifier) {
        case 'SourceTrunk': 
          svnDir += 'branches/CleanBuild/trunk'
          break
        case 'AutoInstaller': 
          svnDir += 'Tools/AutoInstaller'
          break
        case 'ContentAutomation': 
          svnDir += 'Tools/ContentAutomation'
          break
        case 'InternalTools': 
          svnDir += 'Tools/Internal'
          break
        default: 
          throw new GradleException("Invalid svnCheckout classifier '$classifier'")
      }

      String svnCommand = "svn co $svnDir --trust-server-cert"

      //commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "$svnCommand"
      commandLine 'cmd', '/c/', "echo 'Task created'"
      workingDir = "$workspace"
    }
  }
}
```

I then try to run the task 'svnCheckoutSourceTrunk' with this command:

`gradlew -Pworkspace="." svnCheckoutSourceTrunk`

which fails with the error

```
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'svnCheckoutSourceTrunk' not found in root project 'GradleScripts'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I put some `println` statements around the first few lines, and the execution is getting past the if statement, but it's not getting inside the task declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used for declaring the task(s) is incorrect. (Not sure why it's not giving an error.) The first positional argument always need to be the task name:

```
task(taskName, type: Exec) { ... }
```

In a build script, this will also work:

```
task "$taskName"(type: Exec) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems odd that that's an issue, though.  Wouldn't `name: taskName` as the first argument be functionally equivalent?  What's going on there?

Comment: What do you mean by "functionally equivalent"? All overloads of the `Project#task` method have a String as their first positional parameter. As I said, I'm not sure why your syntax doesn't give an error, which is why I raised http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3065.

Comment: Ah, I was confusing it with the overloads of tasks.create().  Never mind.